# Bug found while replacing text in formulas

Tags: vba, excel

I discovered a very interesting **bug** today i.e if it is a **bug**.

Can you please confirm if you can replicate it? If it is a bug and has been not reported then I can file it as such. *I am also ok if any of the Excel-MVPs want to file it as a bug.*

Let's say in `sheet1` in cell `A1`, you have a formula `= $B$2+ $B$3`. Now **ensure** that your cell is selected. Now paste this code in a module.

```
Sub Sample()
    Dim r As Range, sPre As String, sAft As String
    Dim ws As Worksheet

    Set ws = ThisWorkbook.Sheets("Sheet1")

    sPre = "$B$2": sAft = "$C$3"

    On Error Resume Next
    Set r = ws.Range("A1:A2").SpecialCells(xlCellTypeFormulas)
    On Error GoTo 0

    If Not r Is Nothing Then r.Replace what:=sPre, _
                                       replacement:=sAft, _
                                       lookat:=xlPart, _
                                       MatchCase:=False
End Sub
```

Ideally the code should have worked and the `= $B$2+ $B$3` should have changed to `= $C$3+ $B$3` in the **formula bar** but it **doesn't**. **It will work only if you step through it or if you do as mentioned in the next line**

Now do one thing. Select any cell other than `A1` or `A2`. Now if you run the code, the code works as expected.

At first I thought that my excel has gone crazy so I closed and re-started it but I was able to reproduce the above in `Excel 2010` many number of times.

Then I thought it is a `.SpecialCells` issue but the above behavior can be observed with this code as well.

```
Sub Sample()
    Dim r As Range, sPre As String, sAft As String
    Dim ws As Worksheet

    Set ws = ThisWorkbook.Sheets("Sheet1")

    sPre = "$B$2": sAft = "$C$3"

    Set r = ws.Range("A1:A2")

    r.Replace what:=sPre, _
              replacement:=sAft, _
              lookat:=xlPart, _
              MatchCase:=False
End Sub
```

Are you able to replicate it?

Comment: I was able to replicate it in Excel 2013.

Comment: What happens if you immediately use `F2, Enter` after the macro and before the formula bar has updated?

Comment: @Jeeped: it will work then. My answer which has `r.Formula = r.Formula` actually does that in a way :)

Answer (score 7, accepted):

I replicated your issue and got away with it by two ways:

1. Try `ThisWorkbook.Save` after the replace.
2. select other cell than A1 or A2 (cell selected whose formula getting replaced) after replacing formula.

Comment: + 1 So even you were able to replicate it? Awesome. :) Yes, I am aware of the 2nd point. I did mention that in my question. The first one is not actually a solution as there are many occasions when we do not want to save the workbook but just perform some operation on it...

Comment: In your answer, could you confirm the Excel version that you were using while performing the above test?

Comment: I am using excel 2007 still! About selecting cell other than A1 or A2 : I was talking about selecting other cell after formula replacement, not before replacement.

Comment: Ah ok :) Initially I thought it was a `screenupdating` issue but that was not the case.

Answer (score 5):

While many alternatives have been suggested in the other answers for example

1. Select another cell via code
2. Save the workbook

If I do not want to select the cell or save the workbook then is there an alternate way which is better than the above two? Yes, there is. Just tried this and it works

```
Sub Sample()
    Dim r As Range, sPre As String, sAft As String
    Dim ws As Worksheet

    Set ws = ThisWorkbook.Sheets("Sheet1")

    sPre = "$B$2": sAft = "$C$3"

    On Error Resume Next
    Set r = ws.Range("A1:A3").SpecialCells(xlCellTypeFormulas)
    On Error GoTo 0

    If Not r Is Nothing Then r.Replace what:=sPre, _
                                       replacement:=sAft, _
                                       lookat:=xlPart, _
                                       MatchCase:=False

    r.Formula = r.Formula
End Sub
```

But the question still remains that the `Formula Bar` should have updated in the original scenario but it doesn't

Comment: You are right. This is an alternative but actually it should have updated in the first place.

Answer (score 2):

I'm partly able to replicate it, also Excel 2010.

If I run the macro with the cell selected, using the Run option within the Visual Basic Editor, the value in the cell changes to reflect the new formula, but the formula in the formula bar doesn't *show* as updated. But it must be updated because the result changed. If I click out of the cell and back in, the updated formula appears and shows that the search/replace worked.

If I step through the macro in the VBA window, the formula bar does show as updated while the macro runs.

If I run the macro from the Excel window, using Macros -> View -> Run, the formula bar does show as updated while the macro runs.

If I add `r.Select` to the last line of the macro, running it from VBA works.

If I run the macro so it does not update the formula bar, then click into the formula bar, the formula bar shows the old formula but the cell content changes to show the new formula instead of the answer.

Edit: The behaviour appears the same in Excel 2013

Comment: + 1 Thanks for checking it :)

Comment: No proglem. Looks like the same behaviour in Excel 2013, by the way.